# Can I use numba to speed up this for cycle?

Tags: python, numpy, performance, numba

I came across numba, which is a fantastic library to speed up python code.
I was wondering if is there any way to convert this code into numpy code to leverage on numba.
My intention is , for each element of combination of OS_name and client cookie id, to find out what are the differences in each columns and record all the columns in which was shown at least one difference in a dictionary.

I tried doing :

```
@jit(nopython = True)
def gigi():
from tqdm.notebook import trange, tqdm
df = df.applymap(str)

df2 = df.copy()
del df2['client_cookie_id']


s = []
d = {}

for c in tqdm(range(0, len(df.client_cookie_id.unique().tolist()))):

    cid = df.client_cookie_id.unique().tolist()[c]

    for OS in df.OS_name.unique().tolist():

        ### take the indexes of all the occurrences of a single client_cookie_id

        t = df[(df['client_cookie_id'] == cid) & (df['OS_name'] == OS)].index.tolist()

        if len(t) >= 2:

            A = t[0]

            for i in t[1:]:


                B = i

                list1 = list(df2.loc[A])
                list2 = list(df2.loc[B])

                common = list(dict.fromkeys([l1 for l1 in list1 if l1 in list2]))
                remaining = list(filter(lambda i: i not in common, list1+list2))

                t1 = []

                for i in range(0, len(remaining)):

                    t1.append(remaining[i].split('___')[0])

                used = set()
                unique = [x for x in t1 if x not in used and (used.add(x) or True)]
                unique

                for i in range(0, len(unique)):

                    s.append(unique[i])

            s = [x for x in s if x not in used and (used.add(x) or True)]

        d[cid] = s

    else:

        continue

return d

gigi()

d = gigi()
```

But I receive the following error

```
AssertionError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: inline calls to locally defined closures)
key already in dictionary: '$phi28.0'
```

Is someone able to help me?
Thanks

Comment: Where is it taking the time?  Have you measured it?  It is pointless to attempt to optimize a loop unless you know where it is spending most of its time.  Amdahl's Law.  Remember that `numba` can't help the time you're spending in pandas.

Comment: You can replace the entire `for i in range(0,len(unique)):` loop by saying `s.extend(unique)`.

Comment: You can replace the `used = set()` / `unique = [x for x...]` lines by saying `unique = list(set(t1))`.

Comment: I suspect many of your `tolist` calls are unnecessary.  You can iterate through dataframe series just as easily as a list.

Comment: You cannot use external module like tqdm in Numba functions and even if you could, it will not be faster because the jit cannot deal with external module types/calls). Numba only speed up basic numeric codes or the ones with Numpy calls (and few Scipy calls). Lists are supported by Numba but they are not very efficient yet and there are few constraints to fulfil. PyPy is a JIT that support general python codes (despite some minor contains/changes). However, PyPy do not yet support all Python modules and is often not as fast as Numba for Numpy-based/numerical codes.

Comment: Ha, and I forgot to mention Numba does not truely support strings yet (there is an experimental support but all string-based function are not implemented and are not plan to be implemented soon).

Comment: What we're saying is that it is your algorithm that is flawed, not the implementation.  You can use "sort" to arrange your dataframe by client_cookie_id and OS_name, and then just start from the top down, watching for those two values to change.  You don't need three looops.

Comment: Thanks for your tips guys. If you have any other suggestion you're welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't solve your whole problem, but it does show a much quicker way to scan through the rows.  Note that I'm only printing the mismatches here; I'm not gathering them.  Not sure what you wanted for an exact output:

```
import pandas as pd

data = { 
        'client_cookie_id': [ 111, 111, 111, 222, 222, 222 ],
        'OS_name': [ 333, 333, 444, 555, 555, 666 ],
        'data1': [ 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26 ],
        'data2': [ 31, 31, 31, 32, 33, 33 ]
    }


def gigi(df):
    df = df.applymap(str)
    df = df.sort_values( by=['client_cookie_id', 'OS_name'] )

    last = None
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if last is not None and row['client_cookie_id'] == last['client_cookie_id'] and row['OS_name'] == last['OS_name']:
            # Compare the other columns.
            for name,b,c in zip(row.index, row, last):
                if name not in ('client_cookie_id', 'OS_name') and b != c:
                    print("Difference in", name, 
                        "with", row['client_cookie_id'], '/', 
                        row['OS_name'], ": ", b, c )
        else:
            last = row

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
gigi(df)
```

Output:

```
Difference in data1 with 111 / 333 :  22 21
Difference in data1 with 222 / 555 :  25 24
Difference in data2 with 222 / 555 :  33 32
```

Comment: This is very helpful Tim! Thanks a lot.

My idea was to record the difference in each feature in a dictionary like:

cookie_id_5 : [feat1, feat4, feat6]

Maybe I can try to modify your code to get what I want